# Observable seems to persist despite in pipe subscribed by async pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs

In our application, we have a page that should only be navigated to if a certain state is set, let's call it `requiredState$` on **Page C**.

A user has to chose some values on it's way to said page, by doing so he sets the `requiredState$` on **Page B**. The user can start this selection cycle mutliple times, meaning that he will navigate multiple times to **Page C**. Starting point is **Page A**. Upon navigation from **Page A** to **Page B**, the state is resetted.

The order is `Page A (reset states) -> Page B (select state) -> Page C (require state) -> Page A` and so on.

To avoid navigation to **Page C** without without `requiredState$` being set, we have following check in our pipe on **Page C**:

```
this.intermediateObservable$ = this.requiredState$.pipe(
  tap((requiredState) => {
    if (!requiredState) {
      // navigate back to Page B (*)
      this.cancelPipe$.next();
    }
  }),
  // ...
  takeUntil(this.cancelPipe$),
  // ...
);
```

whereas `cancelPipe$` is a simple `Subject`.

The Observable `this.intermediateObservable$` is used in three places

1. To produce the displayed data

   `this.data$ = this.intermediateObservable$.pipe(...)`

   which then is subscribed by `async` pipe in the HTML template
2. When the user selects a category

```
    this.intermediateObservable$.pipe(
      take(1)
    ).subscribe((someData) => {
      // filter out desired category and save to state service
    });
```

3. When the user wants to display informational data

```
    this.modalContent$ = this.intermediateObservable$.pipe(
      // map information to show
    );
```

Again, `this.modalContent$` is passed via `async` pipe to a modal

**Problem**

In the first cycle, everything is fine. The user sets the state on **Page B**, navigates to **Page C** to do some more things, and goes back to **Page A**. Now if he starts the second cycle, he navigates to **Page B** (which just before navigation, resets the required state). This seems to trigger the marked line (*) from **Page C**, resulting in a "double navigation" to **Page B**.

How is this even possible? I am aware that `pipe()` creates a new observable, meaning there are three of them.

1. and 3. are not subscribed directly to, but later via `async` pipe, which should be handled autoatically.
2. uses the `take(1)` operator, which in my understanding should directly unsubscribe afterwards.

Comment: To be completely honest I find it a bit hard to understand your question and it might help if you could slim it down a bit to avoid scaring away potential help by overloading them with information.That being said it seems that a vital piece of information that you could be missing is that every time you call `pipe()` on an Observable, a _new_ Observable is returned and the source Observable is not modified ([see the documentation for this](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators)). Not being aware of this can cause some confusion when then unsubscribing from the _new_ Observables.

Comment: I 100% agree the above answer. I really find it hard to understand your question. If you could remove your domain requirements from this question it really would help to solve this issue. From my point of view it sound like a scan with higher order functions could solve this issue. But this is only a guess. Currently I am not into the specific requirements.

Comment: @tomcek112 thank you for the feedback, I tried to simplify the question

Comment: It is still a little hard to follow and I'm missing some context on how your code is structured (e.g. are your observables in components, a service, a route guard?) -- maybe a stackblitz would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite simple: We did not call `this.cancelPipe$.next()` in successful situations, meaning that `takeUntil()` was not called and the pipe was still active.